# What does "Should we add technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps to Stack Overflow?" mean?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, survey, site-crossover

[The site satisfaction survey](https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect) has the question:

> Should we add technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps to Stack Overflow?

I find it very unclear what this means. It could be:

1. Should we **merge** technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps **into** Stack Overflow?

   - This would make more questions on-topic.
2. Should we **branch off** additional technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps **from** Stack Overflow?

   - This would make fewer questions on-topic.
3. Should **the Stack Exchange network** add more technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps?

   - This would not change the number of on-topic questions.

     > ***These two interpretations [have now been ruled out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392689/what-does-should-we-add-technical-qa-sites-like-server-fault-super-user-and/392887?noredirect=1#comment748982_392887) by staff member Yaakov Ellis ♦.***
4. Should we **make** technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps **into sub-sites of** Stack Overflow?

I'd like to know what this question actually means, but this is also a bug report: Please clarify the survey's text.
[image: Screenshot of survey question]

Comment: The bug is the feature, it is worded to get survey takers to vote "yes".

Comment: @HansPassant Except those that prefer status quo.

Comment: The 0.015%?  Steam-roller.

Comment: Option #2 probably isn't correct because that's how it currently is. Should we <continue doing the same thing> isn't usually a question asked in surveys.

Comment: Have I been living under a rock or something?  Where is this survey you're talking about?

Comment: It only gets offered on question pages (such as when you click to view a question) on SO. so... if you're not actively viewing question pages, you'll never get one.

Comment: Not seeing it @KevinB.  It might be an A/B test.

Comment: it's the survey that's designed to omit meta regulars that aren't also SO regulars

Comment: @KevinB:  I mean, hey - if Meta regulars aren't looking at SO questions all the time, then I could almost agree with that assessment...but I'm really not keen on conspiracy theories or any rumors or innuendo resulting from this.  I would say we don't have enough information to extrapolate *any* meaning from a question like this, honestly.

Comment: i mean, my statements aren't just pulling info out of thin air, this is info that was provided by an employee on "the loop" question.

Comment: I was thinking a 4th interpretation... Moving said sites from .stackexchange.com or their own domain to .stackoverflow.com (for example, serverfault.stackoverflow.com,) which would of course be followed by adding teams/jobs functionality/ads to them. A... less tear down the walls kind of merging.

Comment: @KevinB Wouldn't that fall under the general class of "1"? The exact details of merging (tags, sub-domains,…) are irrelevant.

Comment: well, no, they'd still be their own sites, with their own tags, their own rep, etc

Comment: @Adám No, merging those sites in the way suggested in #1 would mean getting *rid* of those sites and migrating all their users and questions over to SO. Just changing the domains would be... just changing the domains.

Comment: That sounds like a whole lot of ick @KevinB.  It undoes a lot of established precedent with the first three network sites having their own domain as opposed to living under the Stack Exchange umbrella.

Comment: **Please keep comments on-topic;** the *meaning* of the question, not our opinions about the individual possible meanings.

Comment: One could argue that #2 and #3 are already answered by people creating proposals on Area 51 but it could be that they're looking for input from people who don't know that site exists. Also, it's asking if they should add **sites** to Stack Overflow, not **questions**, so that also implies they're talking about changes to the network and not just the Stack Overflow site. It's too ambiguous for me to feel certain they mean any of these (though I don't think they mean #4).

Comment: i **definitely** think that StackOver-flow is Over-crowded... I think that SQL questions should either go to dba.stackexchange **OR** have a separate site for SQL (possibly with PL/SQL, T-SQL, PL/pgSQL and similar) questions. There are ~ 120 SQL questions a day on SO, compared to ~ 20/day **TOTAL** on DBA.SE. IMNSHO, It would be much better to have a different site for SQL programming, be it DBA.SE or a specific SQL (and related) site. Same goes for C/C++? Java? Javascript? Filters help, but I'm for separate sites FWIW!

Comment: Since Yaakov said it implied a kind of merger, doesn't that rule #2 out also?

Comment: @called2voyage It does indeed.

Comment: This Q was how I learned about the satisfaction survey.

Answer (score 16):

I'm ***finally*** in-context to the question being posed in the survey.  With that, I can answer this (but not address the "bug" portion of the original question).

The question is simply:

> Should we add technical Q&A sites like Server Fault, Super User, and DevOps to Stack Overflow?

We're given three answers:

- Yes
- No
- I'm not sure

and a box to elaborate on why we chose what we did.

The way I'm interpreting this question is that it's exploring what the users of Stack Overflow want to see on Stack Overflow, and if it would make sense to consolidate facets that Server Fault, Super User and DevOps cover on the one site.  To be fair, there already *is* overlap - not much, but some.

The *reaction* I have to this question is fairly nonplussed.  If a majority of users said they wanted this, does it *really* mean that Stack Exchange should push for it?  If a majority of users said they **didn't**, would that mean that they wouldn't do it?

A network site - any network site - should have the autonomy to decide what kind of community it wants to build up.  Coupling this with the [The Loop](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), I would hope that this feedback gets an adequate amount of explanation and clarification for decision makers.

I'll admit though, I would *not* want to see these sites combined into one, if for no other reason than it feels like another synthetic attempt at creating value as opposed to exploiting the value already present on the site.

Comment: Maybe even edit your post to make it more clear what you're actually answering and either remove your own opinion (which would belong in a separate Meta discussion post) or mark it as a side note?

Comment: Given that we've already had an explosive reaction to what the actual question *means* or implies, I'm loath to isolate that.

Comment: It sounds like a hint by the company that SO is no longer the only site whose community doesn't get to decide its own fate... apparently SF, SU, and DO look like too tasty of a morsel to not aggressively monetize. At least that's one outlook on it.

Comment: @TylerH:  That's *quite* pessimistic...there's a lot in that quick sentence that takes more to unpack than a comment field would allow me to, honestly.

Comment: I always appreciate your thoughts and, more often than not, even agree with them. But in this case, the quoted question makes literally no sense as written, so all speculation about what it *might* mean is utterly pointless. There’s no real way this can be answered unless a staff member comes by to explain what was intended. I’m sharpening a stick.

Comment: @CodyGray: Fair - I'm not attempting to interpret a meaning to the question, I'm only explaining how I'm reading and reacting to it.  Only a staff member could truly disambiguate this, but at a minimum I'm identifying with one of the OP's perceived readings.

Comment: I think it would also depend on the site.  To me, SU seems the furthest away from SO (maybe arguably SF), whereas the others have a bit more overlap. It seems to reopen the debate on whether we really need separate vim/emacs/etc sites or if they can thrive under tags on a mega site (assuming the SO on-topic scope is broadened).

Comment: @TylerH The pessimistic view is at least the other technical sites seem to have merit to SE. If they start merging in technical sites with SO, what about the non-technical sites?  Most of those probably cost more to support than they bring in.  I'd be more worried about their future.

Comment: @CodyGray How would one attract the attention of staff to this matter? I don't see any "in need of staff intervention" flag…

Comment: @Adám They are already aware of this question, why they need so much time to respond, we can only guess... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341721/which-sites-are-running-site-satisfaction-survey#comment1143256_341722

Comment: @Adám There only way to get staff attention is the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page (in the footer). This page will allow you to send a message to the Community Managers (CMs), who are staff. But...their backlog is kinda long, so an immediate response is unlikely. In this case, I pinged an employee in a private channel (mod hacks), which is what I obtusely referred to above as "sharpening a stick" (as in, getting ready to poke someone about it). I got confirmation from said employee that he would make the appropriate party aware that an official answer is needed here.

Answer (score -57):

It represents something of a merger to some degree of sites that up to now have been completely separate.

Comment: If you just wanted community input on what should be done, couldn't you have asked a more explicitly open-ended question like "What do you think the future relationship between SO and SU, etc. should be?" that makes it more clear to the question-answerer that you are looking for suggestions, rather than leaving everyone uncertain how to respond?

Comment: @DavisBroda yes, that would have been a different approach that we could have done. We chose to go with this approach.

Comment: If you just wanted community input on what should be done, couldn't you have asked a more explicitly open-ended question on a Q&A website?Maybe somewhere with people carrying about the platform like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Open ended but answerable by only Yes/No/I'm not sure ? How could that be open ended if people can't share their insights ?

Comment: @aloisdg meta has a very very small degree of exposure in terms of users. We get much more representative responses from the survey, which is shown (sampled) to all users

Comment: The answer options are Yes/No/I'm not sure. While there's a field to elaborate on one's answer, this field isn't mandatory. Can you explain what information you plan to glean from Yes and No answers when not elaborated upon, since, as explained in the OP, entirely opposite and contradictory interpretations are possible?

Comment: @adam thanks for the respectful and constructive tone of your question. I am not involved in writing the questions or analyzing responses. But I think that the idea is to just gauge the general reaction of survey takers to the idea of "adding technical qa sites to SO". However people interpret this, it represents something of a merger to some degree of sites that up into now are completely separate. If there are strong reactions one way or the other, it can help to inform discovery. This is not intended to solicit specific opinions over how it should take form.

Comment: You comment's *it represents something of a merger to some degree of sites that up into now are completely separate* contradicts your answer post's *We do not have a specific answer at this time as to how it should be interpreted, nor do we want to suggest one interpretation over another* since one of the possible interpretations (number 3 in OP) is that no merging would happen whatsoever. I would appreciate some clarification here.

Comment: @adam you got me. I guess I overspoke. But #3 is not in the cards

Comment: Good to know. Now, if you could please update the survey to clarify that the idea *represents something of a merger to some degree of sites that up into now are completely separate*.

Comment: Obviously most users won't fill out the explanation box (as is true with most surveys when not mandatory) & as you said, the question is confusing on purpose. This is just way for SE to make a change and say "60% of users wanted this! Thanks for your feedback!"

Comment: Thank you for answering. However... I am confused. If the question is open ended and up to interpretation, what are you going to do with the completely worthless results then? If you don't know what my answer means, then it's kinda pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Open-ended question + open-ended response + open-ended interpretation of response = ...... do you even know what you want? (By "you" I mean "StackOverflow / StackExchange" as a company, not you directly, Yaakov. Thank you for reply).

Comment: Respect is earned, not deserved. We do not thank you for an answer that makes absolutely no sense. Having a yes/no option at all contradicts the idea that this question was intended to be open ended. I don't know if you're just not privy to the information needed to answer this question or you're doing your best not to reveal any information (whether by instruction of your superiors or your own volition makes no difference), but this answer is not at all helpful. It is disrespectful to us that you insist we respect such an unbelievable answer.

Comment: The idea is imho very nice - unfortunately, what I can see about the company until now, I expect something what is worser as I could ever imagine. It is not your fault, I simply extrapolate what the company does since I know it. Do your best! Kohelet 9:10.