# Take the 2020 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey-2020

Our 2020 Developer Survey launches today. Whether an active member of the Stack Overflow community or not, we encourage everyone who codes to participate and make their voice heard. The survey will be open until February 25.

**[Take the survey](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_medium=so-meta&utm_source=so-owned&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2020)**

Thank you everyone who gave us feedback on last year's survey and [contributed topic suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389461/2020-developer-survey-any-topic-suggestions) for this year's version. We did our best to take all your ideas into consideration while balancing them with the length of the survey and our ability to measure key insights. As we continue to expand [the ways we gather feedback](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), we included a few questions about the community aspects of Stack Overflow in addition to the usual array of questions about work environments, technology, and tools.

The survey should take about 20 minutes to complete (that's five minutes shorter than [last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey)).

Same as before, any user who completes the survey in its entirety will earn the Census badge and will have the option to get the badge on Stack Overflow or a different technical site in the Stack Exchange network. We updated the badge implementation to prevent users from being unable to earn it if they followed a link to the survey shared by another user.

Anonymized survey results will be available publicly under the Open Database License. You'll be able to download and analyze the dataset later this year. Certain survey answers are treated as personally identifiable information, and therefore excluded from the anonymized results. These questions are highlighted in the survey with a note saying, "This information will be kept private."

Thanks in advance for your time and thoughtfulness.

**If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages.** Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey.

Comment: `Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software.` Well, at least it'll be nice to see the results.

Comment: I did not encounter any errors with uBlock Origin running in Firefox, FWIW. Just finished the survey.

Comment: where are we supposed to leave feedback regarding question wording, etc.

Comment: @Dragonrage Leaving feedback on that as answers to this question is fine.

Comment: Weird that there was such a small selection of languages in the question about languages, and only space to add *one* more.

Comment: I'm a hobbyist coder, not a professional developer. Is there any point in me spending time doing this survey? (FWIW, I generally hate doing surveys).

Comment: I will not be taking the survey for the first time in many years.

Comment: @PM2Ring not really. I'm in your same position and I found it quite boring.

Comment: Is it just me or does this survey feel alot like its pointed to info stack overflow need for the teams* ? Feels like a promotion

Answer (score 68):

Please don't take this merely as a critique, but:

> We did our best to take all your ideas into consideration while balancing them with the length of the survey and our ability to measure key insights.

It seems like none of the top-voted questions proposed in [the topic suggestion post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389461/2020-developer-survey-any-topic-suggestions) have been taken into account (actually, it seems like basically *none* of the proposed questions were considered):

- [How often are you required by your employer to work overtime without proper overtime pay or compensatory time?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389488/3889449) ******
- [How often do you exercise or play sports?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389495/3889449) *****
- [How long does it take you to get to work in minutes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389555/3889449)
- [How many computer monitors are you using for your job?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389474/3889449)
- [If you were looking for a job, how much time (in days) of remote work would you want to be allowed to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389469/3889449) *****
- [Which beverage do you turn into code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389507/3889449)
- [Does your company store sensitive information (password, card numbers, etc...) of customers in plain text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389492/3889449) ******
- [How much time do you spend a week programming on non-work related projects (e.g. hobby projects, open source...)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389534/3889449)
- [You are put in a room with 100 random developers who have similar roles to you. Given the traits you value in a strong developer, how many do you think are better developers than you?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389476/3889449) *******
- [What is your opinion on open plan workspaces?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389493/3889449) *****
- [What do you listen to while you work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389518/3889449)
- [If you lost access to online help/documentation for one workday, could you still develop without using Google, online documentation, or SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389550/3889449) *******
- [Which of the following problems do you repeatedly encounter?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389678/3889449) ******

Some of them were pretty interesting, at least IMHO (I have marked them with asterisks). Why didn't any of these proposed question make it to the survey?

Also, still from the suggestions post:

> We are always on the lookout for fun/silly questions, in the tradition of [have you tried turning it off and on again](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-families-and-it-support) and [tabs vs. spaces](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#work-_-tabs-or-spaces).

I didn't notice any this year :( any reason for that? I've seen some suggestions that would have made sense for this purpose (e.g. [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389507/3889449), [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389518/3889449)).

Comment: The very first one you linked (about overtime) was definitely included. As for the fun questions, I think we have a couple in there, but they're not quite as fun as the ones we've had in the past. I believe that category took the hardest hit when we were trying to get the survey length under control.

Comment: @AdamLear no it wasn't. The question that is asked in the survey is: *"How often do you work overtime or beyond the formal time expectation of your job?"*, which is a foundamentally different question.

Comment: That's fair. The question we asked came from that suggestion and we wanted to avoid enumerating various specific circumstances - e.g. employees earning a salary who don't qualify for overtime pay, freelancers that might work in excess of "regular" hours, etc. etc.

Comment: @AdamLear It'd be the difference between the question actually in the survey and the one in the suggestion list that I'd be most interested in since it gets at the difference between "I work extra hours because I love my job" and "I only work extra hours because my boss is a slave driver".

Answer (score 47):

I have to say, at the end of the survey I was seriously doubting whether I had filled in the Developer Survey or The Loop.

There are increasingly more questions about Stack Overflow specifically and not about development in general. For example where are the questions about:

- What editor do you use?
- What languages do you love/dread?
- How much coffee do you drink?
- Tabs vs Spaces
- Do you work remote?

These are just a handful of questions from the [2015 Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2015#tech-editor). Now instead we have questions like:

- What would you change about Stack Overflow?
- Do you feel welcome?

Which are also asked in The Loop. I feel like the Developer Survey should be more focused on development and developer life than on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 44):

I've completed every survey for the past several years; this year I went through the whole survey, but didn't click submit.

Unfortunately this year's survey has the same feel as the general trend of the past year. There seemed to be very few questions that really ask searching questions about how the community can be improved, and no interesting little trivia like tabs v. spaces.

It's simply a typical 'user satisfaction' survey that many businesses ask (and generally ignore), the difference being that other businesses usually give something in return - at the very least entry into some prize draw. I'm afraid I'm not willing to do SO Inc's customer research for free, especially as the questions don't seem to be asking anything that would improve the current problems.

Comment: I feel your point, and I also had the feeling that the questions were chosen in a way that they will hear what they want to hear. However, there were options to talk about what would improve the problems. For example, _"If you could change anything about Stack Overflow, what would it be?"_ or _"Please elaborate on whether you feel welcome"_. Nevertheless, it still felt more like a customer satisfaction survey than like a developer survey.

Comment: Yes, I thought about writing something in those boxes, but had absolutely no faith whatsoever in it being read, so didn't waste my time.

Comment: @Jesse, you're absolutely right that the answers will show exactly what they want to hear. Hanlon's Razor says that's probably not deliberate, but who knows?

Answer (score 25):

What does this question mean?

> Do you think Stack Overflow should relax restrictions on what is considered “off-topic”?

To:

- relax
- restrictions
- on what is off-topic

So if I answer "Yes", I want to broaden the range of questions that is considered off-topic? What is this triple-negative trickery?

I'm not being pedantic here for once, I genuinely don't know how to parse this sentence.

Comment: Almost as bad as [that uselessly vague question from the site satisfaction survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392689/what-does-should-we-add-technical-qa-sites-like-server-fault-super-user-and).

Comment: It probably means exactly what it states

Comment: I fail to see what "triple-negative trickery" you're talking about. Care to *enlighten me*?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I read it as "...should relax its 'off-topic' restrictions, making more topics on-topic", but you're saying it could also be read as "...should relax the restrictions that limit which topics could be declared off-topic, allowing more topics to be declared off-topic"? I had to re-read it three times to notice that possible interpretation, but I suppose it is there

Comment: I do see what you're talking about now, however, given the position the company has taken on being "welcoming", and how many poorly worded questions have appeared in previous recent surveys, i can only assume they *meant* what most people are likely reading it as, should they make less things off topic.

Comment: Oh boy, with the constant influx of bad and off-topic questions I really do hope they don't make less stuff off-topic. Current off-topic reasons seem fine, I fail to see how removing *any* of the current off-topic reasons would make any sense.

Comment: The big one i can think of is opinion based questions, since they keep advertising that one curl question.

Comment: @yhyrcanus "that one curl question"?

Comment: @Marco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884514/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free/55885729, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384376/are-questions-about-the-motives-of-programming-library-developers-on-topic

Comment: @CodeCaster oh wow, somehow I've never bumped into it. Really beautiful answer by Daniel Stenberg there. I find it kind of funny now since that the author answered, as I wonder if that should still be consider "opinion-based"... that *is* the only true and objective answer coming right from who made the decision.

Answer (score 13):

What does family friendliness mean for a factor in deciding which job to take when compensation is equivalent? I assume it's supposed to be work-life balance or something, but I've never heard the term in the context a a job, so I'm not really sure.

[image]

Comment: It's probably whatever you want it to be. Paternity leave beyond the legal amount, for example, or allowing you to schedule a day off (so less than full-time) to take care of your little ones.

Comment: I assume workplace child care, breastfeeding, permissions to receive visits from family members, etc.

Comment: I suspect it's deliberately open ended because what is a "nice to have" in country X is legally required in country Y and something almost no one in country Z cares about.

Comment: These surveys always assume that you live in USA.

Comment: It could mean lots of other things, including 1) career breaks, sabbaticals, switching to part-time and whether seniority, job security, vacation entitlement, eligibility for promotion, mentoring etc. are preserved. Also, 2) onsite or company-provided childcare facilities/services. Ditto, 3) provisions for elder care. Again, what these boil down to varies greatly by country (and industry, and company). If you see US-specific assumptions, call them out.

Answer (score 7):

Why is "Spring" listed as a web framework?

I've used spring-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-batch ... but not spring-web. Does this count as having used "Spring"? Saying 'no' seems wrong because half of my last job was in Spring. But saying 'yes' seems equally wrong because I didn't use any of the Spring web libraries like spring-web or spring-webflux.

[image]

Comment: I missed it because I don't do any web (so I skipped whole section), but when you pointed I'm curious too.

Answer (score 5):

There is a question:

> What would you like to be able to ask on Stack Overflow (that you can’t ask currently)?

It's not clear what this speicific question is about off-topics. For some reasons I start thinking about other stuff, which is "hard" to use properly without being called rasists, etc. (e.g. pronouns). Reading further it become more clear what it's just about off-topics.

Can you please specifically add word "off-topic" into above sentence or perhaps re-arrange questions to have that one asked the last (then it would be much more clear what it is about)?

Answer (score 3):

The survey should have a "continue" option.

I just accidentally closed the browser tab with the survey and lost 10 minutes of Developer survey input.

It should have an option checkbox at the start to maintain 'state'.

FireFox, Windows 10, AdBlock Plus.

Comment: That's interesting, i pressed the back button and when i resumed it later on my progress was kept

Comment: @NickA I must have clicked the close button. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I've chosen that I am member of SO and following up question appears:

> Please elaborate on your answer to the previous question (seeing yourself as a member of Stack Overflow's community).

I have no idea what elaboration you expect me to write.

Is

> Oh, yeah, I am definitely feel myself a member, thanks for asking

good or what should I write?

Comment: I think they want to know why you see yourself as a member of a community as opposed to just someone with an account who uses the site.

Answer (score 2):

When I goto ( https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_medium=so-meta&utm_source=so-owned&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2020 ) **why do I get this**

[image]

The expected result is **"We're sorry, but the 2020 Developer Survey is closed. See you nect year, when we launch the 2021 Developer Survey"**

Comment: [A bug report for this got raised yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394718/3122701).

Answer (score 0):

I tried taking it, but honestly - I couldn't bring myself to go beyond the race identification part. Sorry, couldn't do it. It just felt wrong to me.