# 2020 Developer Survey says "We're sorry, but the 2019 Developer Survey is now closed"

Tags: bug, blog

When you go to the [2020 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start) which is linked from [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/05/the-2020-developer-survey-is-now-open/) on it, you get the following error:

> We're sorry, but the 2019 Developer Survey is now closed. See you next year, when we launch the 2020 Developer Survey.

I think 2020 should be replaced by 2021 and 2019 by 2020.

Comment: For me, it now says: *"You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired."* Is that because I actually took the 2020 survey while you did not, or has the message been changed?

Comment: I have the same results as OP

Comment: @CodyGray I actually took it but it's possible I didn't take it from this computer/browser. I do remember being asked to take it a second time so I suspect maybe that's related.

Comment: @CodyGray I took the survey and I get the message you got as well, but if I open it in a private window I get the message in the question instead. So probably something to do with that.