# Stack Overflow Survey 2020: IDEs question?

Tags: discussion, survey-2020

Going over the [2020 survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020) I can not find the question about IDEs. It is present in all the other years the survey was made. Is it missing in 2020s survey, or are those results just not presented in that site?

Comment: If I interpreted [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393676/2821954) correctly, then there's no question about IDEs.

Comment: Based on Andrew's answer and the fact that no one has found the IDE question and posted evidence of its existence in the nine hours this question has been up so far, I'm assuming it doesn't exist.  Perhaps this question could also ask _why_ it wasn't included this year.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IDE question was in this year survey, it's strange they deleted it

Comment: Perhaps someone at Prosus is an old-school "hater" of VS Code :)

Comment: Kos, every survey done since 2017 has this question in it. That's why it's so strange that it's missing in the 2020 survey

Comment: I think I remember that they wanted to shorten the last survey. Maybe they felt like the IDE question doesn't add much and left it out in order to shorten the survey.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393676/365237), some of the things that were left out were:

> - What editor do you use?
> - What languages do you love/dread?
> - How much coffee do you drink?
> - Tabs vs Spaces
> - Do you work remote?

In general, the survey was criticized of leaving off lot of developer-oriented questions.

Comment: HOW COULD THEY LEAVE OUT TABS VS SPACES

Comment: I only indent with backspaces.

Comment: ^H^H^H^HWorks for me.

Comment: `/*         */`comment base indent; since it's commented it doesn't matter if it's tab or spaces

Comment: So they left out the answers to the only interesting questions we still had in 2020. Wow.

Comment: [Indentation with semicolon](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/pszopm/little_contribution_to_the_indentation_war/) is the way to go!